# KeyError though definitely in the Dictionary

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, keyerror

I have an index that contains this:

```
IRD\0.jpg [  4.64939594e-01   6.48846030e-02   2.00261129e-04       0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00  ...    7.34290807e-04   6.90233335e-02   2.02463999e-01]
```

but when called here:

```
for (k, hist) in index.items():
    # compute the distance between the two histograms
    # using the method and update the results dictionary
    d = method(index['IRD\0.jpg'], hist)
    results[k] = d
```

it comes up with this error:

```
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-b7c782484164> in <module>()
# compute the distance between the two histograms
# using the method and update the results dictionary
d = method(index['IRD\0.jpg'], hist)
results[k] = d
```

and I don't really get why?
Help would be highly appreciated and I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious but I am fairly new to this :)

Comment: Is `index` actually a list of tuples of length 2, as you imply?

Comment: It's not like python can get "confused" and not realize the key is there. If you're getting a key error then you're doing something wrong. print all the keys of `index`, in the loop,  and you'll see

Comment: @jphollowed the index contains the key (the file name) and the  value is the pixel values and I will

Comment: @ExJasmine Sorry, disregard my first comment, I read something wrong. Still, print out the keys of the dict. just add `print(k)` in the loop and comment out the `d = ...` line for now, then let the loop go through `index`, printing all keys.

Comment: So I printed the key with: for key, value in index.iteritems() :
    print key and it came out with: IRD\20.jpg
IRD\18.jpg
IRD\1.jpg
IRD\3.jpg
IRD\2.jpg
IRD\4.jpg
IRD\14.jpg
IRD\28.jpg
IRD\17.jpg
IRD\11.jpg
IRD\27.jpg
IRD\10.jpg
IRD\23.jpg
IRD\9.jpg
IRD\19.jpg
IRD\13.jpg
IRD\15.jpg
IRD\26.jpg
IRD\7.jpg
IRD\8.jpg
IRD\29.jpg
IRD\21.jpg
IRD\5.jpg
IRD\22.jpg
IRD\24.jpg
IRD\30.jpg
IRD\12.jpg
IRD\25.jpg
IRD\0.jpg
IRD\16.jpg
IRD\6.jpg 
which is what I expected

Comment: @ExJasmine Well, wait, if its `IRD\0.jpg`, why do you have it written as `IRD\x00.jpg'? Its a string, so that will be interpreted literally.

Comment: @jphollowed Sorry I changed it to that as its the error, I tried the way you said and it printed IRD\20.jpg which isn't what I was after

Comment: @ExJasmine Ah jeez, I read wrong again. But I think I see your problem, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Do `for key in index: print repr(key)` instead. If a string prints as `IRD\0.jpg` its python string representation is `"IRD\\0.jpg"` or `r"IRD\0.jpg"`.

Comment: @tdelaney The first one, youre right. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

It's because `\` is the escape character in strings. If you want it to be interpreted as an actual char in the string, then you have to escape it:

```
>>> print('x\0')
x
>>> print('x\\0')
x\0
```

so change `index['IRD\0.jpg']` to `index['IRD\\0.jpg']`

Comment: Thank you so much, error is now gone!
(I mean I've been trying to fix this for hours and it's so simple so thank you, thank you, thank you!)